# Katalon Studio - Stop test suite execution if a test fails

Tags: automated-tests, katalon-studio, test-suite

I would like to stop test suite execution in Katalon Studio when a test fails. Can someone tell me if this can be achieved in Katalon as I am new to this tool?

Comment: You can check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56767341/global-variables-katalon-studio/58856611#58856611) to see how to skip a single test case based on other test case statuses. This can be expanded on for a solution on test suites. So, it could be done, but not out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56767341/global-variables-katalon-studio):

1. Create a Global Variable with boolean value set to `false` (You need to do this before actually running the test case/suite):

```
GlobalVariable.SKIP_REMAINING_TESTS = ''
```

2. Create a test listener with the following code

```
@BeforeTestCase
def sampleBeforeTestCase(TestCaseContext testCaseContext) {
    if(GlobalVariable.SKIP_REMAINING_TESTS==true){
        testCaseContext.skipThisTestCase()
        println "Test Case skipped"
    }
}
@AfterTestCase
def sampleAfterTestCase(TestCaseContext testCaseContext) {
    if(testCaseContext.testCaseStatus=='FAILED'){
        GlobalVariable.SKIP_REMAINING_TESTS = true
    }
}
```

Before each test, `@BeforeTestCase` will check if `GlobalVariable.SKIP_REMAINING_TESTS` is true (it is false by default) and will skip the test if it is.
After each test, if the test case is failed it will change `GlobalVariable.SKIP_REMAINING_TESTS` to true and all subsequent test case in that test suite will be skipped.